# Can every idempotent ideal be generated by an idempotent?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

This problem comes from this commutative algebra problem

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, $I$ is a finite generated
> ideal of $R$ such that $I^2=I$, then exists $e\in R$ such that $I=Re$.

This problem can be proved using the Nakayama lemma, but the condition for finite generated is necessary? If I isn't finitely generated, does the conclusion still hold? follow

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, $I$ is an
> ideal of $R$ such that $I^2=I$, then exists $e\in R$ such that $I=Re$.

How to prove this? Or there is a counter-example to disprove.

Comment: What about the ideal $K[\mathbf{Q}_{>0}]$ in $K[\mathbf{Q}_{\ge 0}]$?

Comment: Of course the question is strangely posed. If the ideal is not f.g., obviously it cannot be generated by an idempotent. The question is rather whether "finitely generated" can be removed from the assumption (and the answer is no, i.e. there exists an infinitely generated example).

Comment: GuoJi: no, this is certainly not what I wrote.

Comment: oh, that would be ideal generated by idempotent.
What does the $K[\mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}]$ above mean?

Comment: For a semigroup $(S,+)$, $K[S]$ is the vector space with basis $(e_s)_{s\in S}$ and this becomes a $K$-algebra with product $e_se_t=e_{s+t}$ (this is called "semigroup ring" or "semigroup algebra"). For instance $K[\mathbf{N}]$ is just the polynomial algebra $K[t]$ (assuming the convention $0\in\mathbf{N}$).

Comment: Is the question you want to ask “Is there an infinitely generated idempotent ideal?”. Because the answer to the question in the title is trivially “no”.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I just want to know idempotent ideal $I$ in the ring $R$ (Not necessarily finite generated), can there still be an $e\in R,e^2=e$, such that $I=Re$?

Comment: Well that assumes that 'infinitely generated' really means 'not finitely generated'.
Well one could also interpret 'infinitely generated' as generated by an infinite set. Then the answer to the question in the title is trivially 'yes'.

Comment: @HenrikRüping Does anybody use “infinitely generated” in that way? Are there really people who would say that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinitely generated abelian group?

Comment: The title has been edited by OP to reflect the intended question (which I answered negatively in the first comment).

Comment: @GuoJi: The title speaks about an idempotent, but the body of the question does not say anything about the element $e$. Do you want $e^2 = e$?

Comment: Just to repharase my example, it is the ring $\bigcup_n k[t^{1/n!}]$ with the ideal $\bigcup_n t^{1/n!}k[t^{1/n!}]$. Of course it has plenty of variants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a counterexample from analysis. Let $R= C[0,1]$, the ring of real-valued continuous functions on the unit interval, and let $$I = \{ f \in C[0,1] : f(0) = 0 \}.$$
Then $I$ cannot be generated by any idempotent $p$, for if it were $p$ would have to satisfy $p(0)  =0$ and $p(x) = 1 \ (x \neq 0)$, contradicting continuity. However you can check that $I^2 = I$: if $f\in I$ and $f(x) \geq 0 \ (x \in [0,1])$, then $f = (\sqrt{f})^2$ shows that $f \in I^2$; for general $f \in I$, decompose the function into its positive and negative parts.

Comment: Edited as I realised there was a much simpler answer than my original response.

Comment: Your quantification is not clear to me, but I think "$p(x) = 1$ ($x \ne 0$)" means "$p(x) = 1$ for *some* $x \ne 0$" (rather than, as I originally read it, "$p(x) = 1$ for *all* $x \ne 0$"). \\ Incidentally, while a simple counterexample is good, I don't think there's anything wrong with giving an additional counterexample, too.

Comment: It means $p(x) = 1$ for all $x \neq 0$. If $p$ generates $I$ then it cannot vanish at some $x \neq 0$, since this would force $f(x) = 0$ for every $f \in I$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451055/can-every-idempotent-ideal-be-generated-by-an-idempotent/451066#comment1166026_451066), ah, good point. Even the existential quantification would be enough, since a function that is an idempotent in $C([0, 1])$ can only be $\{0, 1\}$-valued, hence cannot assume both $0$ and $1$ as values; but, as you point out, a more explicit approach is available.